# Загрузить картинку в форму (не через кнопку в форме)

Tags: php

Есть ли способ загрузки картинки в форму не через кнопку в форме (`Выберите файл`)? Имею в виду какие-то встроенные функции в PHP или какой-нибудь другой способ.

Есть папка `img`, в ней картинка `image.jpg`.

Нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы с формой в поле `type="file"` уже была загружена эта картинка.

Comment: Hет, способа нет. Хорошего Вам настроения!

Comment: @Igor довольно качественный ответ!

Comment: Зачем вам это? Типа noimage?

Comment: @Zanetti `Выберите файл` - это `HTML`. `PHP` - это серверная часть. Если вам нужно чтобы картинка уже была, то делайте, для этого у формы есть `value`

Comment: Вам для тестирования PHP, потому что надоело жамкать кнопку? Тогда могу предложить 2 способа: `curl` и `Selenium WebDriver`. Подробности нужны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы с формой в поле type="file" уже
>   была загружена эта картинка.

Такого способа, к сожалению, нет (если не брать в учёт разработку расширения для браузера).

Причина кроется в политике безопасности: если бы мы со страницы сайта могли обращаться к произвольным файлам на диске, то это бы позволило красть файлы с настройками программ, электронные кошельки, файлы с лицензиями и так далее.